# Alt=Media not downloading file when access token is provided as query parameter

Tags: google-drive-api

Problem you have encountered:
When downloading a file using get request and authorizing through query parameters an error is present. As soon as the alt query parameter is removed the request preforms as expected and returns a file resource body.

What you expected to happen:
Preforming a get request on [https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[File](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%5BFile) ID]?supportsAllDrives=true&access_token=[Access Token]&alt=media would download the file properly with no issues, Instead an error is returned [Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfHD7.jpg)

Steps to reproduce:

-> Create a file in google drive
-> Get an access token either by authorizing a service account or using a user account
-> Take the ID of the file created and the access token of the account used and make a request to [https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[File](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%5BFile) ID]?supportsAllDrives=true&access_token=[Access Token]&alt=media replacing [File ID] with the file id and [Access Token] with the access token
-> See results. Expected: File downloads. What actually happens: [An error is given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfHD7.jpg)

Other information (workarounds you have tried, documentation consulted, etc):
Just for testing I tried removing the alt parameter to see if the issue only persists when trying to download files and indeed it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the reason of your issue is due to `access_token` is used as the query parameter. From January, 2020, the access token cannot be used with the query parameter like `access_token=###`. [Ref](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api) In this case, please include the access token in the request header instead of the query parameter.

For example, the sample curl command is as follows.

```
curl \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer [Access Token]" \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[File ID]?supportsAllDrives=true&alt=media'
```

#### References:

- [Upcoming changes to the Google Drive API and Google Picker API](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api)

  > First, we’re making changes to authorization for the Google Drive API. If you authorize download requests to the Drive API using the access token in a query parameter, you will need to migrate your requests to authenticate using an HTTP header instead. Starting January 1, 2020, download calls to files.get, revisions.get and files.export endpoints which authenticate using the access token in the query parameter will no longer be supported, which means you’ll need to update your authentication method.
- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

Comment: Great! Thank you for the response. Well now I have one more question. I did know that authorization in headers is just better for security and for overall stability, with that said there is a reason I was trying to use query parameters. I want to redirect to link that will download a file from my drive. And as we know you cannot pass headers with redirects. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you for telling me that, I'm new here. New Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66827970/authenticating-google-api-request-without-headers

Comment: @pohogie Thank you for your response. I will check your new question. And when I found the solution, I would like to answer it.