# Authenticating Google API Request without headers

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I want to redirect to a google api link (Example:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[File ID]?supportsAllDrives=true&alt=media)
```

That will download a file from my drive and as we know you cannot pass headers with redirects for authorization so I'm wondering how else I can authenticate the request.

Answer (score 1):

You cant send the header like that, only if it was a webContentLink .

If its a binary file then a file.get will give you a webContentLink which you can use to download the file,  or you can run a [file.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) which will allow you to export the file that way.

The only way you can download a file is to be authorized to download the file by the user who owns that file.